# Coupon code functionality

Tags: coupon

I'm new to magento. I go through the Coupon Code in Promo-Shopping cart Rule

can you anyone tell me how many coupon code customer can used on site.

Comment: single customer can use only 1 coupon code at a time.

Comment: hi suppose i have get three diffrent coupon codes , can i used it seperatedly. or  i have to create another registration for it. please reply . if u not get my point . please give me u r mail id , so i can discuss with u

Answer (score 1):

There is option while creating the coupon code -

1. **Uses Per Coupon** field, specify the number of times a customer can use this coupon code if you would like to provide a limit. If not, leave blank.
2. **Uses Per Customer** field, specify the number of times a customer can use this promotion if you would like to provide a limit. If not, leave blank.

Answer (score 1):

As @bijal-bhavsar already said in the comments, **during the checkout** you are able to **add ONE coupon code to the order**. So only one cart rule with a coupon is used. Beside of this, you can have as much rules (catalog and cart) applied as you want. When all the dependencies are fulfilled, they get applied automatically.

There are extensions to remove this limit and add more coupons, just google for it.

Answer (score 0):

For more detail regarding creating coupon codes in magento, you can go through [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_5)

Comment: Please sum up the most important parts behind the link to have the information here, when the link is once gone.